# How to check if checkbox is checked inside a particular form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a jQuery function to check if a checkbox is checked like so:

```
if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){ }
```

I have two set of check boxes in two separate forms. When I use above code it checks for checkboxes in both forms. I want the `if` condition only for one form.  How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:eq()` selector. Try the following:

```
if ($('form:eq(0) input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) { } // first form checkboxes
if ($('form:eq(1) input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) { } // second form checkboxes
```

please note that `:checkbox` selector is *deprecated* you can use `input[type="checkbox"]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can include your `form` in `selector` by using its `id` or `class` etc,

By using form id

```
if ($('#yourFormId input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){ }
```

By using form class

```
if ($('.yourFormClass input:checkbox:checked').length > 0){ }
```

By using the index of form, eq(0) gives you first form and eq(1) second so on...

```
if ($('form:eq(0) input:checkbox:checked').length > 0) { }
```